# Numerical and graphical summaries of data distribution and relationships

Tags: r, self-study

I'm studying regressions. I was asked to write graphical and numerical summaries of the distribution of four variables and their relationships. What is a proper way to do it say for example in R? The data points are of the form $(x_i,y_i,z_i,t_i)$ where $0.5<x_i<35,\quad 0.3<y_i<14,\quad 0<z_i<9.15,\quad 0.4<t_i<19.$

Answer (score 1):

What about a scatter plot matrix? That could be a set of scatter plots for all combinations of $x$, $y$, $z$, and $t$ and histograms or kernel density plots of each variable on the main diagonal. There are some examples with code here: http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/scatterplot.html